# Identifing continous sequences of a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column': [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,]
})

    column
0        0
1        0
2        1
3        1
4        1
5        2
6        2
7        2
8        2
9        1
10       1
```

I am interested in identifying all continuous sequences(e.g. no jump in the index number) that matches some condition, the latter is trivial, e.g.

```
df[df['column'] == 1]

    column
2        1
3        1
4        1
9        1
10       1
```

The next step is to identify the indexes 2-4 and 9-10 as two discrete entities. I could(and have) make a regular python loop with some logic that does this to give something like(do not necessary need the indexes, just a way to extract the sequences themselves)

```
[(2,4), (9,10)]
```

But this seems unnecessary, and I am wondering if anyone have a more of a 'pandas' / efficient method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# group by consecutive values
g = df['column'].ne(df['column'].shift()).cumsum()
# identify rows with "1"
m = df['column'].eq(1)

out = (df[m]
       .groupby(g, sort=False)
       .apply(lambda g: (g.index[0], g.index[-1]))
       .tolist()
      )
```

Output: `[(2, 4), (9, 10)]`

Answer (score 1):

Identify the target groups with:

```
grp = df['column'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

Then group by those, pull first and last index for each group.  Then select only group 1 and convert to list:

```
df.groupby(['column',grp]).apply(lambda x: (x.index[0],x.index[-1])).xs(1).to_list()
```

**Result**

```
[(2, 4), (9, 10)]
```